# Observable interval flatMap combination doesnt work

Tags: android, rx-java2

I'm new to rxjava 2 and i'm trying to execute someMethod in the background with a given interval and use the result on the UI thread. Can someone point me where i made mistake in my code or even better provide optimal code that does the job i need?

```
@Override
  protected void onStop() {
    subject.onNext(Long.valueOf(10005));
    observable.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    super.onStop();
  }

private void initAzimuthUpdater() {
    subject = PublishSubject.create();

    observable = Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .takeWhile(new Predicate<Long>() {
          @Override
          public boolean test(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxxxxxx test: " + aLong);
            return aLong != Long.valueOf(10005);
          }
        });

    observable.flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Float>>() {
          @Override
          public ObservableSource<Float> apply(@NonNull Long aLong) throws Exception {
            return PublishSubject.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Float>() {

              @Override
              public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Float> e) throws Exception {
                e.onNext(someMethod());
              }
            });
          }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new Observer<Float>() {
          @Override
          public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onSubscribe:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            isRunning = true;
          }

          @Override
          public void onNext(@NonNull Float o) {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onNext:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            //update UI
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onError:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
          }

          @Override
          public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onComplete:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
          }
        });

    subject.mergeWith(azimuthObservable);
  }
```

Comment: Please use `Observable.create()` instead of `new Observable`.

Comment: Worked like a charm ;), thank You, one more question, how do I now stop this observable from emiting items, calling `observable.unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io());` didnt work @akarnokd

Comment: Stop when and under what condition(s)?

Comment: I basicly want it to stop, I read that it is impossible to do directly, so i tried sending a value to test that decides if the observable continues to emit values, i edited the code above with my attemps, can You help me? @akarnokd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `DisposableObserver` and `subscribeWith`, save the `Disposable` into a `CompositeDisposable`, then call `clear()` on it from `onStop()`. The `Observable` operators return a new instance so ignoring their return value will have no effect on the original flow.

```
CompositeDisposable composite = new CompositeDisposable();

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    composite.clear();
    super.onStop();
}

private void initAzimuthUpdater() {

    Disposable d = Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
       .flatMap(new Function<Long, ObservableSource<Float>>() {
          @Override
          public ObservableSource<Float> apply(@NonNull Long aLong) 
                  throws Exception {
            return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<Float>() {

              @Override
              public void subscribe(@NonNull ObservableEmitter<Float> e) 
                    throws Exception {
                e.onNext(someMethod());
              }
            });
          }
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeWith(new DisposableObserver<Float>() {
            @Override
            public void onStart() {
                Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onSubscribe:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
                isRunning = true;
          }

          @Override
          public void onNext(@NonNull Float o) {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onNext:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            //update UI
          }

          @Override
          public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onError:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
          }

          @Override
          public void onComplete() {
            Log.d(TAG, "xxxxxxxx onComplete:" + System.currentTimeMillis());
          }
        });

    composite.add(d);
}
```